# Can we resize converted base64 image into custom size in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, base64

I have converted image into base64 image, this image original size is `height: 200` and `width: 150`. I need to convert this image size to `height: 133` and `width: 100`. I gone through sencha io image resize concept. It is not converting and also once I applied sencha io to url it won't display image. Can any one tell me how to customize size of converted base64 image in sencha touch2 styles.

**Here is my code:** in this below code `height: 133px; width: 100px;` assigned, but for this some part of image is coming. Original image size is `height: 200px; width: 150px;`. I need to customize this one as `height: 133px; width: 100px;`

```
 .aboutclsT{
     background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAADICAYAAAAKhRhlAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2Fy......K5CYII') !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 133px;
     width: 100px;
 }
```

**SenchaIO image code:**

```
background: url('http://src.sencha.io/100/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAADICAYAAAAKhRhlAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2Fy......K5CYII') !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 133px;
     width: 100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. I have added `background-size: 100px 133px;` it is working fine. You guys can assign how much height and width want.

****here is code.****

```
.aboutclsT{
     background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJYAAADICAYAAAAKhRhlAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2Fy......K5CYII'') !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     **background-size:100px 133px;**
     height: 133px;
     width: 100px;
 }
```